# Grouping in datagrid - rows not getting displayed

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, grouping

I have to group the data int the datagrid.
I have done following for that:

1. Have added the style to resources as:

> ```
> > <Style x:Key="GroupHeaderStyle"
> > TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
> >         <Setter Property="Template">
> >             <Setter.Value>
> >                 <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
> >                     <Expander IsExpanded="False"
> >                      >
> >                         <Expander.Header>
> >                             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
> >                 </Expander.Header>
> >                         <ItemsPresenter />
> >                     </Expander>
> >                 </ControlTemplate>
> >             </Setter.Value>
> >         </Setter>
> >     </Style>
> ```

2. I have applied the style as:

> ```
>     <dg:DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Name="dgAuthor" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
> AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="17" RowHeight="25">
>                 <dg:DataGrid.GroupStyle>
>                     <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}">
>                         <GroupStyle.Panel>
>                             <ItemsPanelTemplate>
>                                 <dg:DataGridRowsPresenter/>
>                             </ItemsPanelTemplate>
>                         </GroupStyle.Panel>
>                     </GroupStyle>
>                 </dg:DataGrid.GroupStyle>
>            </dg:DataGrid>
> ```

3. I have infoList as a ObservableCollection and have assigned it as itemssource as follows:

   ListCollectionView lcv = new ListCollectionView(infoList);
               lcv.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Author"));
               dgAuthor.ItemsSource = lcv;

where Info is class which has Author,Book,Year properties.

I have to group the datagrid on Author property.
I am able to display the explander but cannot see any rows in it.
Can anybody tell me whats wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` explicitely solves the problem.
I also added the column definitions.